# Find the sum of a column values based on unique cases,max value and specific value of other columns in the dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below and I want to find the sum `qty` of unique `case_id` for the max `lifecycle` that it has when the `in_out` value is `out`. That means that I will add for this case `17694` and `28290`

```
lifes<-structure(list(case_id = c(3396922, 3396922, 3396922, 3396922, 
3396922, 3396922, 3396922, 3396922, 3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 
3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 
3397364, 3397364), lifecycle = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), qty = c(0, 19977, 19977, 2386, 
17591, 17481, 17480, 17694, 0, 31276, 31276, 9, 31267, 31538, 
6644, 6120, 3740, 3480, 28290, 28290), in_out = c("in", "out", 
"in", "out", "in", "out", "in", "out", "in", "out", "in", "out", 
"in", "out", "in", "out", "in", "out", "in", "out")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), case_id = "case_id", activity_id = "activity", activity_instance_id = "action", lifecycle_id = "registration_type", resource_id = "resource", timestamp = "timestamp", class = c("eventlog", 
"log", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
library(dplyr)

lifes %>%
  filter(in_out == 'out') %>%
  group_by(case_id) %>%
  summarise(max_value = qty[which.max(lifecycle)]) %>%
  pull(max_value) %>% sum()

#[1] 45984
```

If you run only till `summarise` step you can see the `max_value` for each `case_id` -

```
lifes %>%
  filter(in_out == 'out') %>%
  group_by(case_id) %>%
  summarise(max_value = qty[which.max(lifecycle)])

#  case_id max_value
#    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 3396922     17694
#2 3397364     28290
```

Answer (score 1):

This works using dplyr package :

```
library(dplyr)

lifes %>%
    filter(in_out == "out") %>%
    arrange(-lifecycle) %>%
    filter(duplicated(case_id) == F) %>%
    sum()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

does this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)

    lifes |>
      group_by(case_id, in_out) |> 
      mutate(lifecycle_is_max = lifecycle == max(lifecycle)) |> 
      group_by(in_out, lifecycle_is_max) |> 
      summarise(x = sum(qty))
```

Comment: should have added that it needs `dplyr` of course. Note that no filters are being used so you get all results for all groups